# How to move file from Windows Form Application to Android device (Android Tablet) connected via USB?

Tags: c#, android, winforms

I want to transfer .txt file from Windows Form Application (C#) to Android device (Android Tablet : **Samsung Galaxy - Android 4.4.2**). Android tablet will always connected with specific computer via USB cable and then end user will Windows Form Application through send (Click on Send button) selected file to Android device.

**What i did**
I am trying to transfer file via ADB driver implementation in my windows application. But i am confuse how to get connected tablet path for send file.

I want to know all possible best way or implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: [Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/datascenarios) -- *Virtual Folders* sections.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks! for comment but, i am looking for C# code integration only.

Comment: Look for `IShellFolder` (or Shell32 Folder) `CopyHere()` and `BrowseForFolder()`.

Comment: You can include the Shell Interop COM objects adding a Project reference to `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation`. -- It has some portability issues, but should get you started in a semi-managed way.